# Receiving Memory Warining for UITableView in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have used `UItableViewCell` default title and detail label before, it worked fine without any warning, Now I have customized the table view cell, I have used label and added as subview, and I am getting image from file also for contacts... Now I am receiving frequently memory warnings and it is crashing, I am reusing identifier like below still warning showing up.. What could be the problem, Am I not freeing the label's memory properly or fetching image from file frequently, causing this? Any idea...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Get the path of the file.
    get__path(file_path);

    NSString *fle_path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:file_path];

    fle_path = [fle_path stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c%ld%s",'/',obj->user_id,".jpg" ];

    NSString *combined_name = [NSString stringWithCString:obj->combined_name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithCString:obj->email encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    CGRect rect = [cell frame];
    UIImageView *img_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55)];
    UILabel *name_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 7, rect.size.width-70, 20)];
    UILabel *detail_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 27, rect.size.width-70, 20)];

    // Set Image
    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fle_path];

    if (cellImage != nil) {
        [img_view setImage:cellImage];

    }

    // Set name

    [detail_label setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 18,rect.size.width-70, 20)];
     name_label.text = combined_name;

     name_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Italic" size:18];
        detail_label.text = email;

     [cell_italic.contentView addSubview:img_view];
     [cell_italic.contentView addSubview:detail_label];

     cell_italic.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     rect.size.height = 55;
     [cell_italic setFrame:rect];
     return cell_italic;
```

When should I free the memory for above labels... ?

Comment: allocate views only cell== nil

Comment: And this, every time for every cell ... UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fle_path]

Comment: When should I free memory for those labels?, Will it be handled...?

Answer (score 1):

your cell and cell_italic are two different type of cells, because cell is of default UITableViewCell and cell_italic is your custom cell, you have to cast UITableViewCell to cell_italic type cell.also one thing- you have allocated cell & returning cell_italic.

you can cast like this:

```
CustomResultCell *cell; 
 cell = (CustomResultCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

update 1: change

```
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: That is a mistake, it is returning cell only see edit... I am dequeuing every time, I am getting Null so in next line I am allocating if it is NULL, So my labels also will be allocated for each call.. How to handle this.